# Is it possible to get the effect of a newline character in ServerListPingEvent `event.setMotd()`?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I've learned that one can use `\n` in the server.properties config file.

Unfortunately this does not suit my needs as I need to set the message of the day dynamically while the plugin is running and I want to use `event.setMotd()`, rather than trying to play with modifying the server.propertiers file itself.

Currently I do this with well counted white space:

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onPing(ServerListPingEvent e) {

        int rnd = r.nextInt(allMotds.size());
        String tps = new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(LagProcessor.getTPS());

        final String msg = "\u00A73\u00A7l        RVA-Survival 1.16.5 \u00A7r\u00A77 |  TPS: " + tps +
                "           \u00A7r\u00A76\u00A7o" + allMotds.get(rnd);

        e.setMotd(msg);
    }
```

This won't work in the future as I want to have the first line also be customizable.

I know I can't use Unicode `\u2424` since that just prints the actual graphic symbol only.
`\n` does not work here either sadly.

In my research I've been unable to find any solutions outside of using the server.propertiers to set the motd which again doesn't work here for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In-case no better answer is found, I should share my current workaround.

**I wrote this into the class that handles the ping events:**

```
    private static String center(String ln) {
        StringBuilder whiteSpace = new StringBuilder();

        // trim and truncate strings
        String trimmed = ln.trim();
        int charTotal = trimmed.length();

        final String trunc;
        if (charTotal >= 60) trunc = trimmed.substring(0, 60);
        else trunc = trimmed;

        // count missing whitespace
        int diff = 60 - charTotal;
        int half = diff / 2;

        int i = 1;
        while (i <= half) { i++; whiteSpace.append(" "); }

        // add the whitespace and make the tail end a bit longer
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(whiteSpace + trunc + whiteSpace);
        while (out.length() < 62) out.append(" ");

        return out.toString();
    }
```

**Then I make use of it like this:**

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onPing(ServerListPingEvent e) {

        int rnd = r.nextInt(allMotds.size());
        String tps = new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(LagProcessor.getTPS());

        final String msg1 = "\u00A73\u00A7lRVA-Survival 1.16.5 \u00A7r\u00A77 |  TPS: " + tps;
        final String msg2 = "\u00A7r\u00A76\u00A7o" + allMotds.get(rnd);

        e.setMotd(center(msg1) + msg2);
    }
```

**Result:**
[image]

*Note:*
Keep in mind the centering is technically irrelevant and what is important is the method you implement that adds the correct amount of trailing white space.

For your convenience, that would look like this:

```
    private static String fillLine(String ln) {

        // trim and truncate string
        String trimmed = ln.trim();
        int charTotal = trimmed.length();

        final String trunc;
        if (charTotal >= 61) trunc = trimmed.substring(0, 61);
        else trunc = trimmed;

        // add the whitespace tail
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(trunc);
        while (out.length() < 62) out.append(" ");

        return out.toString();
    }
```